# Better way to wrap a source element from a Directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm writing a Directive (using AngularJS 1.2.0-rc2, if that matters) that adds a "clear" button (think of the "x" button that the browser adds for `<input type="search">` elements) to an `<input>`.

As the "clear" button is injected from the Directive and is positioned absolutely, I'd like to contain both the existing `<input>` and the newly added "clear" button in a wrapper element that has `position: relative` to ensure proper positioning of the "clear" button.

The declared HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="myField" data-ng-model="someModel" data-search>
```

The Directive I have so far:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('search', function() {
  var
    clear = angular.element('<a href role="button" class="btn x" style="display:none">&times;</a>'),
    wrapper = angular.element('<div style="position: relative"></div>');

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
      element.wrap(wrapper.append(clear));

      // more code that's not relevant to my question
    }
  };
});
```

The HTML I end up with is

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <a href role="button" class="btn x" style="display: none">&times;</a>
  <input type="text" id="myField" data-ng-model="someModel" data-search>
</div>
```

which is what I'm after, but I'd like to ideally template the two new elements and abstract the DOM manipulation out of my `link` function.

I feel like there's probably a better way to go about this using either or both `replace`/`template` and `transclude` options, but I'm not sure how to retain and use the source element (with all of its attributes and data bindings) with either of those options.

Also note that even though my sample has an `ng-model` defined on the source element, that should be considered optional. I'd also like to keep the Directive restricted to attributes (`restrict: 'A'`).

Comment: Can you append some Plunker/Fiddle? Thanks

Comment: I think that what you want to do cannot be done the way you want to, inputs do not have a closure, so transclusion is useless unless you wrap the input in another element. What problem do you have with your approach? it seems clean enough to me. Maybe you should consider to compile the wrapped html, but besides that, i can´t see the problem. Is there any problem that you should fix?

Answer (score 6):

Transclusion is probably what you're looking for. Here is some updated code.

Template:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <a href role="button" class="btn x" style="display: none">&times;</a>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('search', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    // template: '', // string template of the HTML above, or better yet
    templateUrl: '', // relative URL of an HTML file containing the above template
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-search>
  <input type="text" id="myField" data-ng-model="someModel">
</div>
```

You should only use one of either template or templateUrl in the directive, I would lean towards templateURL because I hate string templates.

You can still include a link function if you need more logic.

The replace property will replace the existing DOM element you apply the element to entirely, while leaving this property out will preserve the element and put your template inside of it. Up to you how you would want this configured.

Thinking about it some more, if you did this:

```
transclude: 'element'
```

You could just do this in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myField" data-ng-model="someModel" data-search>
```

Comment: [I've attempted your proposed solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBtXM/), but if you inspect the results, you'll see that (for some reason) the `style` value is duplicated and all the `<input>` attributes are applied to the wrapping `<div>`.

Comment: You're right, there is some funkiness when you use transclude: 'element' with replace. I would say just stick with the original answer (using transclude: true with a parent div) rather than transclude: 'element'. Seems to work fine.

Comment: @Adam Why even have the input text field separately in the HTML? He can have it directly in the Template, instead. That way, all he has to call is the div with the attribute on it (Even better if he can use the Element name directly as he already has a div in his template). Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: The transclude: 'element' would work. You just need to implement it explicitly in your link function. [See here how it's done](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html#understanding-element-transclusion).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a better way to design a reusable component is isolate scope and directive controller. In your case, I don't see your logic, so I will make it simple using just isolate scope.

Your template file:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <a href role="button" class="btn x" style="display: none">&times;</a>
  <input type="text" id="myField" data-ng-model="model">
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('search', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      model:"=model"
    },
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {

      // more code that's not relevant to my question
    },
    templateUrl:url-to-your-template
  };
});
```

Use it:

```
<search model="someModel"/>
```

Or just:

```
<search />
```

If you need to use it as an attribute, try:

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('search', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{
      model:"=model"
    },
    replace:true,
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {

      // more code that's not relevant to my question
    },
    templateUrl:url-to-your-template
  };
});
```

Use it:

```
<div search model="someModel"/>
```

or just:

```
<div search />
```

Comment: Two things I'm not fond of with this solution (that I probably should make clear in my question): it assumes the source element has a model and uses a custom element instead of an attribute.

Comment: @André Dion: In my opinion, it's not necessary to assign an attribute to an element and *replace it with `replace:true`*. Just declare a new type of element and use it (like a reusable component)

Comment: @André Dion:`it assumes the source element has a model`. It's ok that the model is optional in this case.

Comment: You have to keep in mind the supporting custom elements in <IE8 requires extra code (which gets annoying) and some of us like to avoid it entirely. He also specifically said he wanted to avoid custom elements.

Comment: The extra hoops for IE is precisely why I want to avoid custom elements.

Comment: @André Dion:this solution does not assume the source element has a model. The `model` property in isolate scope is separate and could be optionally bound to a property of your controller scope.

Comment: Your template still has a hardcoded ID and input element type, which is bad practice. He did say he wanted to use transclude to make it more dynamic.

Comment: @Adam: just forgot to remove that. When working with angular, we really don't need an id. Even if you need to pass in an id, you could still create another property on the isolate scope and use `{{ }}` to bind it.